# AJAX jquery Form Post not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to post a form using ajax.

Right now, the code I have is

```
$("#sub").click(function() {     
    var tag = $("#tagbar").val();
    var opinion = $("#op").val();
    alert($("#expressform").serialize());
    $.post("dbfunctions.php", $("#expressform").serialize());
});
```

This works, but it takes a long time to post and add to the database (thats what dbfunctions does) compared to how long it took before, when I was using a form action and refreshing the page. Why is this?

Also, if I remove the alert, the script stops working completely. I can't figure out anyway in which this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you cancel the default action of the button by returning false from the click handler:

```
$("#sub").click(function() {     
    $.post("dbfunctions.php", $("#expressform").serialize());
    return false;
});
```

Also instead of subscribing for submit button clicks, it's better to subscribe to the submit event of the corresponding form directly:

```
$("#expressform").submit(function() {     
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

This way you are no longer hardcoding any urls in your javascript files. You are simply unobtrusively AJAXifying your form.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use below function for submit the data 
through Ajax form Submit

$('#form1').ajaxForm({
      success:function(response){
          $('#save_data').html(response);

});


$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {  

          $('#form1').submit();

  });
```